# Server doesn't render ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to render an ejs file but it doesn't work, I don;t have an idea of what the problem could be.

confirm_email.js

```
res.render("confirm_email", JSON.parse(req.query.v));
```

app.js(main file)

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views','./views');
```

app folder sructure

```
models
node_modules
public
    -(css, js, jquery, fonts...)
routes
    -signup
        -signup.js
        -confirm_email.js
views
    -confirm_email.ejs
    -index.html
    -portfolio.html
app.js
package.json
package-lock.json
```

Comment: *Does not work*? An error? An empty response? Whatever else?

Comment: it doesn't display an error in the console

Comment: Could you describe in detail what exactly you do to claim it doesn't work?

Comment: In my `signup.js` file i'm redirecting to the ejs file when an ajax post  method is handled with success`res.status(201).redirect(`/signup/confirm-email?v=${JSON.stringify(nUser)}`)`.  I just checked and in the network dev tool tab it shows that the `.../confirm_email?v=...` has a type of xhr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your configuration for your views files. try this

```
//your views folder directory
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views"); // set express to look into this folder to render our view
app.set("view engine", "ejs"); // configure template engine
```

Comment: Thank you. That was part of the problem but the actual one is that the response goes to ajax post call (i didn't mention it my bad) and i had to redirect from client side.